# Normal subgroups, direct product and monomorphism problem

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and let$H,K$ be normal subgroups of $G$. Let $\pi_H,\pi_K$ be the projections on $H$ and $K$ respectively. Show that the map $$f:G/(H \cap K) \to G/H \times G/K$$

defined as $f(\overline{x})=(\pi_H(x),\pi_K(x))$ is a monomorphism.

First of all I am not so sure what the projection means in this case, for example, take $\overline{x}=x(H \cap K)$, is the projection $\pi_H(x)=Hx$?

Another doubt that I have is: if $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups, does this imply $H \cap K$ is normal? I am pretty sure that condition is necessary in this problem, but I don't know how to show $H \cap K$ is normal.

Assuming $H \cap K$ and if I've understood the function correctly, I would like to know if this proof is correct:

- Injectivity: suppose $f(x(H \cap K))=f(y(H \cap K))$,

then $(\pi_H(x),\pi_K(x))=(\pi_H(y),\pi_K(y))$, which means $(Hx,Kx)=(Hy,Ky)$, so $$Hx=Hy,$$ $$Kx=Ky.$$

From the fact that $H,K$ are normal subgroups, it follows $xy^{-1} \in H \cap K$, which implies $x (H \cap K)=y (H \cap K)$.

- Homomorphism: $f((H \cap K)x)((H \cap K)y))=f((H \cap K)(xy))$ $$=(\pi_H(xy),\pi_K(xy))=(H(xy),K(xy))$$ $$=((Hx)H(y),(Kx)(Ky))=(\pi_H(x)\pi_H(y),\pi_K(x)\pi_K(y))$$$$=f(x)f(y).$$

I would appreciate if someone could tell me how can I show $H \cap K$ is normal and if my solution is correct (btw, anyone can write a better well-written/different/shorter solution as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way of looking at the normality of $H \cap K$ is that if $\sigma$ is any inner automorphism of $G$ then
$$
(H \cap K)^{\sigma} = H^{\sigma} \cap K^{\sigma} = H \cap K
$$
in your proof the normality of $H$ and $K$ is used (a) to guarantee that $G/H \times G/K$ is a group, and (b) (via normality of $H \cap K$) in your demonstration that $f$ is a homomorphism -
$$
f((H \cap K)x)((H \cap K)y))=f((H \cap K)(xy))
$$
but it is not required where you invoke it ("From the fact that H,K are normal subgroups, it follows...")

otherwise your proof seems fine

Answer (score 1):

$H$ being normal implies that for any $h \in H$, we have $g^{-1}hg \in H$. If $h \in K$ as well and $K$ is normal, then $g^{-1} h g \in K$ as well. So, $H\cap K$ is normal.

I think your proof is correct.